# Composition relations with jHipster

Tags: jhipster, aggregation, composition

I am learning jHipster. My entity relationship model has projects and files. A project can have zero to many files, and a file always belongs to exactly one project.

```
project <(1:1)-----(0:*)> file
```

Users interact with the application similar to using an IDE. First, after opening the initial website they always have to select which project they want to work in. (Of course they can also create new projects, or perhaps delete an old one.) Only then they get access to all resources added to a particular project such as files.

As a consequence, my REST API should logically look like this (to get a single file):

```
GET /projects/{:projectId}/files/{:fileId}
```

In the backend, depending on whether fileId is a UUID or not, I might even have a method:

```
findFileByIdAndProjectId(String fileId, String projectId)
```

The problem is that jHipster creates all entities in a "flat way". Each entity seems to have its own REST API without nesting, and there is simply a reference to an other entity rather than proper composition. Adapting the generated code is quite a bit of work as it requires lots of changes both on the frontend and the backend, but more importantly, it probably breaks the ability to re-create my code when an entity has changed.

I am curious: What different options do I have, and which one would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Custom code is the way to go though there are few tricks that can help you:

- Using DTOs so you can aggregate entities in service layer
- Extending generated classes both in backend and frontend so that you don't change generated code, see [excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WVpwIUEty0), [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/agoncal/custom-and-generated-code-side-by-side-with-jhipster) and [code samples](https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-talks/tree/master/2018-06-JHipsterConf) from Antonio Goncalves

Comment: They recommend using query filters. I am not entirely sure what is meant in this context. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose he meant "JPA entity filtering", see https://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/ You could ask him for confirmation on twitter